# AWS SQS as JMS, messages sent/received from an on-premise app

Tags: amazon-web-services, jms, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I am totally new to AWS and have limited java experience. However, my assignment is to help support a hybrid solution where a java client app installed on-premise, is sending JMS messages (Spring JMS) to Amazon SQS. A server app running on EC2 will pick up the message from SQS, process it and put a response message to another queue. Then the same client app will pick it up the response message and the process completes.

My question is, can a client app installed on-premise use JMS to send messages to Amazon SQS? If yes, how is the message exchange secured (SSL)?

Additional question: AWS is billing like 0,4$ per millions of messages. When my client app do polling requests, will they be considered like a message even when a queue is empty?

Kind regards

Allan H.

Answer (score 1):

An on premise application can easily send messages to a SQS queue.  It could translate those messages from JMS and send them via SQS.  All AWS endpoints support SSL (see [this list](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sqs_region) for the endpoint names) and, while you can use HTTP, the default is HTTPS.

In standard JEE the code would look like below - it shouldn't be bad to translate into Spring:

```
@MessageDriven(...)
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;

        MyObject myObject = (MyObject)(objectMessage.getObject());
        // stringify myObject - just an example
        String stringToSend = new Gson().toJson(myObject);

        SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest()
                    .withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .withMessageBody(stringToSend);

        amazonSQS.sendMessage(sendMessageRequest);
    }
}
```

This code leaves out the initialization but it hopefully will give you an idea of what you'll need.

As far as costs, you've obviously seen the [SQS pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/).  I'll admit that I'm not sure about the polling costs.  There is some data transferred in an "empty" poll but I'm not positive what that'll cost.

Comment: Thx for the reply. So this piece of code can run on-premise and send messages to SQS? Not quite sure about your JMS answer so let me try be more clear: can I use JMS (JMS 1.1 should be supported by SQS) with some security enabled on-premise (ex. SSL) to send/receive messages to/from SQS?